# undefined method `request' for nil:NilClass when using gem to install fastlane

Tags: ruby, rubygems

when I am using this command to install fastlane in macOS Catalina 10.15:

```
sudo gem install fastlane -v 2.177.0

or

sudo gem update fastlane
```

shows this error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `request' for nil:NilClass
(base)
```

I tried searching from internet but seems no issue about this problem.what should I do to fix it? This is my ruby version info:

```
$ ruby -v                                                                                                                                                                      ‹ruby-3.0.0›
ruby 3.0.0p0 (2020-12-25 revision 95aff21468) [x86_64-darwin19]
(base)
```

and this is my rubygem info:

```
$ gem -v                                                                                                                                                                       ‹ruby-3.0.0›
3.2.3
(base)
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I tried following steps and issue resolved

```
gem cleanup
brew uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin
sudo gem install cocoapods-user-defined-build-types
pod install --repo-update
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried to upgrade the version and works:

```
gem install cocoapods -v 1.11.3
gem install fastlane -v 2.206.2
```