# IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/FMDB.framework" failed: No such file or directory (2) while archiving flutter app

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I'm trying to archive my flutter app to export it to the Apple Store.
The app can be run without any problems, but the archiving process result with a fail.

Xcode is at the latest version that i can download (Version 14.3 (14E222b))
Flutter is updated

I've tried theses commands to try to remove the problem :

```
flutter upgrade
flutter clean
flutter pub get
cd ios
pod deintegrate
rm -f Podfile.lock
pod install
pod update
pod install
sudo gem install cocoapods
sudo gem uninstall ffi && sudo gem install ffi -- --enable-libffi-alloc
```

After these commands i go into Xcode, delete DerivedData, Clean Build Folder, change Minimum Deployment into Pod > FMDB > General > Minimum Deployment > set to 12.0

And now I test to build an Archive.

After 30 seconds (average), i've got this error :

```
PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/mateo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dehetosspbhbthhgdgvjmdurocom/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-B1164030238D389C328552D1.sh (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    cd /Users/mateo/Documents/Dev/App-VE-app/ios
    /bin/sh -c /Users/mateo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dehetosspbhbthhgdgvjmdurocom/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-B1164030238D389C328552D1.sh

mkdir -p /Users/mateo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dehetosspbhbthhgdgvjmdurocom/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks
Symlinked...
rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --links --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "../../../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/FMDB.framework" "/Users/mateo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dehetosspbhbthhgdgvjmdurocom/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Runner.app/Frameworks"
building file list ... rsync: link_stat "/Users/mateo/Documents/Dev/App-VE-app/ios/../../../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/FMDB.framework" failed: No such file or directory (2)
done

sent 29 bytes  received 20 bytes  98.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/810eba08-405a-11ed-86e9-6af958a02716/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code when archiving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75928909/command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code-when-archiving)

Answer (score 134):

Please open xcode and click Pods-Runner-frameworks file on left panel.

[image]

go to 44. line

```
source="$(readlink "${source}")"
```

change to (add -f)

```
source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"
```

Note : Please don't forget the space after '-f'

[image]

Clean build folder and run again.

Comment: This works, but question is ... why? Why is cocoa pods generating non working scripts? Did someone already reported bug? Or is this only bug of new xcode?

Comment: Hello user 2621907, the '-f' flag is used to follow symbolic links and return the path of the actual file. In this case, it ensures that the correct path is used for the 'source' variable. The original command without the '-f' flag may not work as expected if the source file is a symbolic link.

Comment: After an archive works, the next time the line 44 will go back to how it was, how can this be fixed to persist? @ZorkanErkan

Comment: @YassinSameh Right click > Show in finder > Right click on file > Box check "locked"

Comment: Seems like "pod install" command resets this file. But this answer helped me with xCode Version 14.3 (14E222a).

Comment: This answer was a godsend.  On a deadline to get a build out and got this error.   Searched for hours and finally found this.  Thx so much!

Comment: @George I am very pleased.

Comment: this works like charm running xcode 14

Comment: Sorted it for me straight away, thank you!

Comment: This solution worked for me; one detail others might skip as I did on the first go: the space after 'f' is crucial.

source="$(readlink -f "${source}")" will succeed
source="$(readlink -f"${source}")"  will fail

Comment: @BorisKingma I added it as a note. Thanks.

Comment: @BorisKingma I'm so glad you fixed the problem. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Men it works, hustled for days xcode 15

Comment: to make it work after running pod install just add this
post_install do |installer|
 system('sed -i \'\' \'44s/readlink/readlink -f/\' \'Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks.sh\'')
end

Answer (score 32):

Update cocoapods to 1.12.1.  Then do a new 'pod install'

Comment: thanks! (simply run `brew upgrade cocoapods` to check if you've installed with brew, otherwise check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39481636/updating-to-latest-version-of-cocoapods)

Comment: Wow! Works like magic. So this seems to be a bug that has been fixed by CocoaPods. 

Comment: This worked for me but I actually had to uninstall cocoapods first. I followed this instruction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66585376/undefined-method-request-for-nilnilclass-when-using-gem-to-install-fastlane

Answer (score 2):

I think Greg Anderson's solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76213903/10917762 is the way to go as it fixes the issue permanently and will not overwrite the fix once you run `pod install`.

However for me a simple `brew upgrade cocoapods` did not work so I had to run:

```
gem cleanup
brew uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin
sudo gem install cocoapods-user-defined-build-types
pod install --repo-update # run this in your XCode project
```

The solution is from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73403613/10917762

Comment: Thanks bro! This is the solution that works for me!

Answer (score 0):

it is not just related to this FMDB.framework in flutter, i was facing such type issue in react native such as
"Showing Recent Messages Multiple commands produce '/Users/macbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/chaingpt_mobile_app-bfxesfwxwnyicehioaqymsqfaclk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/chaingpt_mobile_app/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/RCTI18nStrings.bundle'"

Solution: delete the last file such as TI18nStrings.bundle inside pods folder.
it resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the plugin into `pubspec.yaml` and then uninstalling and reinstalling cocoapods works for me

```
# Uninstall the local cocoapods gem
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods

# Reinstall cocoapods via Homebrew
brew install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the fastest work around solution
Just add this

post_install do |installer|
system('sed -i '' '44s/readlink/readlink -f/' 'Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks.sh'')
end

Answer (score -3):

This problem seems to be recent and the solution that worked really well for me was to go back to Xcode 14.2.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).