# Xcode Build and Run success, but Archive fails

Tags: xcode, frameworks, archive

My app builds and runs successfully (Xcode 14.3) and has been already archived successfully multiple times.

I just implemented a minor code change for a bug correction and started the process for Appstore submission with a new Archive. Archive fails with the following:

building file list ... rsync: link_stat "/Users/jean-marc/Xcode/Swift course/Tesla1/../../../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/ASN1Swift.framework" failed: No such file or directory (2)

This happens inside the step: "Run custom shell script'[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks"

Looked for the reported missing file. Found it under:

/Users/jean-marc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tesla1-hhkvkydmrxwnahbhcowfjhmszdny/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Tesla1/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/ASN1Swift.framework

which is not where it is looked for when the error happens.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning Derived Data and project build folder?

Comment: I have found the solution there:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75977278/intermediatebuildfilespath-uninstalledproducts-iphoneos-fmdb-framework-failed Looks like a bug with 14.3